# Advices on what kind of structure to use in Python to store music informations

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm working on a Music project, and I'm retrieving informations about artists, but I don't know what shoul be the best structure to use to store the data. I was thinking about a simple DataFrame, but I want to insert informations like number of albums, and for everyone of them, other infos like number of song, genre, year, lyrics of the songs and so on...

My last idea was to work with json, and that's the proposal:

```
jsondic = {
        'artist': 'name',
        'genre': 'rock',
        'link': 'linksite',
        'year': 0000,
        'n_album': 10,
        'album': {
            'title': 'titalbum',
            'release': 'releaseyear',
            'tracks': {
                'id': 1,
                'title': 'songtitle',
                'lyrics':'boby content of songs'
            }
        }
    }
```

is that a good idea? can you suggest better ways? maybe faster also in terms of computation capacity, because I estimate to store 10,000 artists (with all the songs and the lyrics)

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks good at the first glance.
2. Add code to populate the structure. (this will enable us to test it)
3. Add one code to print the structure.
4. 10000 is not (assuming you are
   not string musics). Repeat one single example 10000 times to get
   initial of perfo? 
   5.Mobile or desktop app?

Comment: -That's the point man, I don't know how to work with Json... it is better to work with dictionaries and then convert it into json?
- I suppose 10000 artists because I'm scraping some websites to grab all the infos. 
- for the moment no app, but maybe desktop

Comment: No need of Json at this stage. Populate manually one single instance.

Comment: well... to be honest,  I don't know how. I have to create a string and the convert it into json? maybe if you can link me some nice guide.. thanks a lot